# Bluetooth server application using java WTK 2.5.2 crashes on launch

Tags: java, bluetooth

For the last few days, I've been developing an Android application which goal is to use the touch screen to move the cursor on my computer.

I've first implemented the communication between the mobile phone and my computer using WiFi. Everything is ok but I'd like to be able to use bluetooth.

On the phone side, everything is simple and easy. What I am not able to achieve is the bluetooth server.

I've downloaded and (painfully) installed the Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 and the JavaSE jdk.

For now my code is very simple and looks like this :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.bluetooth.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;

public class BluetoothServer extends Thread {
    //private static LocalDevice localDevice;
    static LocalDevice localDevice;
    DiscoveryAgent agent;

    //start server
    private StreamConnection startServer() throws IOException{
        System.loadLibrary("zayit");

        //Create a UUID for SPP
        UUID uuid = new UUID(0x1101);
        //Create the servicve url
        String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=SampleSPPServer";

        //open server url
        StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );

        //Wait for client connection
        System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
        StreamConnection connection = streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

        return connection; 
    }
}
```

I've added external jars to get the import for javax.bluetooth and javax.microedition.

The project builds normally but When I launch it, it crashes with following error :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb27d6400, pid=25778, tid=2999303024
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzayit.so+0x23e400]  kvm_resetOperandStack+0x8
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ixm/workspace/RemoteControlServer/hs_err_pid25778.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Without the System.loadLibrary(), I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javax.microedition.io.Connector.isNetworkMonitorActive()Z
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.isNetworkMonitorActive(Native Method)
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.<clinit>(Connector.java:153)
    at BluetoothServer.startServer(BluetoothServer.java:20)
    at BluetoothServer.run(BluetoothServer.java:43)
```

I have no clue what I should do or try. I did not find anything helpful on the internet.

Can someone help me? Maybe the real question, is: "Is it possible to develop a Java application (for a computer) that use bluetooth?"

Thank you very much!

Best regards,

ixM

Answer (score 0):

I've juste noticed that I installed the wrong version of Java (SE instead of ME). I will not try to install the right one since it is designed for mobile devices.

Instead, I will give it a shot with bluecove. I did not investigate that way before because I thought it was a python library for windows. Apparently, this is not the case and I was blind or stupid at the time I read the project page for the first time.

Sorry